# Centered hat over bold letter with subscript in \newcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros, subscripts

I'm relatively inexperienced with LaTex and I'm trying to use `\newcommand` in a larger project.
I have several cascaded `\newcommand`s that I can't get to behave the way I want:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\gyrobias}{\vec{b}_{g}}
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\hat#1}
```

With this I would like to be able to write `$\est{\gyrobias}$` to get a hat over a bold **b** with a subscript g. This almost works, but the hat is over the whole expression, not just b.

A similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135906/90802) covers essentially this with the help of `\expandafter`. So I tried the following

```
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\expandafter\hat#1}
```

But this gives me the following compilation error:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $ $\est{\gyrobias}
```

If I add curly braces to `\hat{}`, which is what I'm used to, the text compiles fine, but the hat is not moved to where I want it.

```
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\expandafter\hat{#1}}
```

Removing the curly braces from `\hat` to match the answer in the linked question and defining `\gyrobias` without the `\vect` gives the desired hat placement, but of course, now the b is no longer bold

```
\newcommand{\gyrobias}{b_{g}}
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\hat#1}
```

I suspect I need some more `\expandafter`s, but I have no idea where as I don't fully understand what they do.

---

### Edit

I got it to work with a slight modification to @steven-b-segletes answer:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\expandafter\hat#1}
\newcommand{\gyrobias}{{\vec{b}}_{g}}
```

I would now like to achieve the same thing with a couple of slightly more complicated symbols:

```
\newcommand{\rquat}[2]{{\overline{q}}^{#1}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\camrot}{\rquat{O}{C}}

\newcommand{\pos}[4]{_{#4}\vec{#1}_{#2 #3}}
\newcommand{\trans}[3]{\pos{t}{#1}{#2}{#3}} %\trans{from}{to}{in}
\newcommand{\campos}{\trans{O}{C}{O}}
```

I want `\est{\camrot}` and `\est{\campos}` to place the hat only just above the "central letter". Currently it is set over the whole `\rquat`/`\trans`. Similarly `\dot{\camrot}` and `\dot{\est{\camrot}}` etc should be placed on top of the central letter only, and not the sub/super-scripts

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the `\expandafter` trick you get `\hat\vec{g}_g` which is illegal.

Comment: I would use a special `\hatgyrobias` command rather

Comment: That would probably the quickest way to achieve the desired result. However, I was hoping to get something modular that would allow reuse and changing of individual parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key was to set your redefinition of `\vec` in its own group (as denoted with the extra set of braces).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\gyrobias}{\vec{b}_{g}}
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\hat#1}
\begin{document}
$\est{\gyrobias}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this approach does bad things to `\vec` in some other way, one could always apply the extra group to the definition of `\gyrobias`, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\gyrobias}{{\vec{b}}_{g}}
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\hat#1}
\begin{document}
$\est{\gyrobias}$
\end{document}
```

**FOLLOW UP**

With this follow up, I address the issue of getting a `\hat` or `\dot` over the intended letter, using the syntax of the OP.  However, it does not address the issue of multiple diacritics over the same letter, as in `\dot{\est{\camrot}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\gyrobias}{{\vec{b}}_{g}}
\newcommand{\rquat}[2]{{\overline{q}}^{#1}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\camrot}{\rquat{O}{C}}
\newcommand{\pos}[5][]{{_{#5}}#1{\vec{#2}}_{#3 #4}}
\newcommand{\trans}[4][]{\pos[#1]{t}{#2}{#3}{#4}} %\trans{from}{to}{in}
\newcommand{\campos}[1][]{\trans[#1]{O}{C}{O}}
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\applydiacritic{\hat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Dot}[1]{\applydiacritic{\dot}{#1}}
\newcommand\applydiacritic[2]{\ifx\campos#2\campos[#1]\else\expandafter#1#2\fi}
\begin{document}
$\est{\gyrobias}$\medskip

$\camrot\quad\est{\camrot}\quad\Dot{\camrot}$\medskip

$\campos\quad\est{\campos}\quad\Dot{\campos}$\medskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

The OP points out that the above code does not work with `amsmath`.  Here is a fix for that, though I note that `amsmath` package affects the placement of diacritical marks over the letter "t", and I have verified that it is not related to my solution here, which can be seen in the first line of my output (when `amsmath` is inserted/removed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}% THIS PACKAGE EFFECTS PLACEMENT OF DIACRITICS OVER \boldsymbol{t}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\gyrobias}[1][]{#1{\vec{b}}_{g}}
\newcommand{\rquat}[3][]{#1{\overline{q}}^{#2}_{#3}}
\newcommand{\camrot}[1][]{\rquat[#1]{O}{C}}
\newcommand{\pos}[5][]{{_{#5}}#1{\vec{#2}}_{#3 #4}}
\newcommand{\trans}[4][]{\pos[#1]{t}{#2}{#3}{#4}} %\trans{from}{to}{in}
\newcommand{\campos}[1][]{\trans[#1]{O}{C}{O}}
\newcommand{\est}[1]{\applydiacritic{\hat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mydot}[1]{\applydiacritic{\dot}{#1}}
\newcommand\applydiacritic[2]{%
  \ifx\gyrobias#2\gyrobias[#1]\else
  \ifx\campos#2\campos[#1]\else
  \ifx\camrot#2\camrot[#1]\else
  #1#2\fi\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{t}\quad\hat{\boldsymbol t}\quad\dot{\boldsymbol t}$\medskip

$\gyrobias\quad\est{\gyrobias}\quad\mydot{\gyrobias}$\medskip

$\camrot\quad\est{\camrot}\quad\mydot{\camrot}$\medskip

$\campos\quad\est{\campos}\quad\mydot{\campos}$\medskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar WIthout any package, `\boldsymbol` was undefined.  The OP didn't tell me where to find it, so I searched the site, and answers using `\boldsymbol` loaded `bm`.  If there is a preferred way, please let me know.

Comment: Both do the same with `bm` package. But one can directly use `\bm{#1}` instead.

Comment: @HarishKumar I see.  Thank you for the tip.  I do note that `\boldsymbol` is a bit more descriptive than `\bm`, however.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I got it working with your second suggestion, but I had to modify the `\est` to `\newcommand{\est}[1]{\expandafter\hat#1}`. Now I have a slightly more complicated case that does not seem to work with this method. (See my edit) Can you assist me with this as well?

Comment: @Nicolas Please see my follow-up.  It address one of your issues, but not the one of multiple diacritics.

Comment: This looks great! Unfortunately, I it does not work if I include the package `amsmath`. It gives me an `Argument of \rquat has an extra } $\camrot\quad\est{\camrot}` error

Comment: @Nicolas Please see fix.  I ended up having to do to `\gyrobias` and `\camrot` what I had already done for `\campos`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately it looks like one loses the modularity I was hoping for. The command `\applydiacritic` becomes quite complicated as I have several more variables that I want to do this with. So it might actually be easier for me to just define the commands manually. Nevertheless I will accept your answer as it does what I asked.

Comment: @Nicolas I understand completely.  It was fun to explore, but the modularity you desire requires a whole new syntax, in order to get diacritics to apply to something not necessarily at the beginning of the argument.  Thanks for the acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different strategy: redefine `\vec` to have a `*`-variant for the hat form.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\hat{\bm{#2}}}
    {\bm{#2}}% 
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\gyrobias}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\vec*{b}_{g}}
    {\vec{b}_{g}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\vec{x}_{g}+\vec*{x}_{g}+\gyrobias+\gyrobias*$

\end{document}
```

[image]